# When should I expect the device endpoint to return empty for traits?

Tags: nest-api

I'm querying the endpoint for a specific device ID for my thermostat, here https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits#fields.

Most of the time the response is fully populated like what the above documentation details. However, every once in awhile the `traits` field is completely empty `"traits": {}`, but all other top level fields are populated.

It's not clear to me when this happens. I wonder if it's because the thermostat is not responding? Or went to sleep?

I do need to handle this gracefully, but it would be good to know when to expect this. Thanks!